# Sys.require vs Sys.loadscripts vs Sys.loader

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I'm finding it hard to find clear documentation on loading scripts using the Microsoft AJAX framework.

Can someone tell me the difference between:

- Sys.require
- Sys.loadscripts
- Sys.loader.registerScripts
- Sys.loader.defineScripts

Answer (score 1):

`defineScripts` allows you to specify a set of JS files that your site uses, and the dependencies between them e.g. jQueryUI has a dependency on jQuery. There's an example [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/HOW%20TO%20Load%20a%20Custom%20Script%20with%20Dependencies.ashx).

If you then use `Sys.require` to indicate that one of those scripts is used on a page, that script plus it's dependencies will be downloaded in parallel, there's an example of this at the bottom of the that page.

`loadScripts` accepts an array of paths to JS files, which are similarly downloaded in parallel, there's some details [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/HOW%20TO%20Load%20a%20Custom%20Script.ashx).